# Counting Barrels / Hough Transform

Tags: image-processing

i'm trying to find a way to count barrels on an image.

For this I'm using Hough Transformation.

I tried my code first recognising eyes and it works excellent. But now the problems is when i try to find more than one center on the image.

For the eye case, I just use Hough with an accumulator, that later will tell me the position of the posible center.

[image]

but if I try with this image, it only prints a circle, instead of 10.

any recomendation?

Comment: Does the edge-detection step work as intended? In other words, are the circles well-represented in the output of edge detection? If information is already lost in this intermediate step, later steps wouldn't produce useful outputs either.

Comment: You can also consider a color-based (RGB, HSV or YCbCr) classifier of the wood color of the barrels. This will give you solid blobs of circles, which can then be analyzed by several algorithm approaches.

Comment: I'm working on matlab. So, if I first tried with:
 im = rgb2gray(im);
ed=edge(im,'canny');

the image I obtain is : http://puu.sh/bRmQS/ca0197ac99.png

It has a lot of noise, so I ignored it.

After, I tried with:
umbral=graythresh(im);
bin=im2bw(im,umbral);
ed=edge(bin,'canny');

and the image obtanied have well-represented circles,
http://puu.sh/bRnvk/43f15a6bae.png
 but even though, I used the center detector, to see if it works for at least a barrel, but it doesn't.
For the second method I obtain
http://puu.sh/bRozq/caa6a1d212.jpg
First method: http://puu.sh/bRoIG/d4da4fcf0d.jpg

Comment: Your image links are dead. Any change that they can be found and edited into the question?